# How to remove duplicates in my python script?

Tags: python, regex, duplicates, file-manipulation

I have used a regex search to filter down some results from a text file (searching for ".js") which has given me roughly around 16 results some of which are duplicates. I want to remove duplicates from that output and print either onto the console or redirect it into a file. I have attempted the use of sets and dictionary.fromkeys with no success! Here is what I have at the moment, thank you in advance:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import sys

pattern = re.compile("[^/]*\.js")

for i, line in enumerate(open('access_log.txt')):
    for match in re.findall(pattern, line):
        x = str(match)
        print x
```

Comment: As an aside, you are using python 2 which is end of life. Move to python 3 if you can.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. SO is not a code-writing service, so please post your best attempt, even if it didn't work. For reference see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). By the way, Python 2 hit end of life in January, so unless you need it for a job or something, stop learning it and learn Python 3 instead. Python 3 is much better.

Comment: Just put the matches into a list then see [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/4518341)

Comment: Restricted to python2 unfortunately, working on a VM created by someone else with explicit request to use python 2.

Comment: @wjandrea I did post my best attempt above? Just looking for advice on how best to do it?

Comment: You were on the right track with sets, that is the right data structure for the problem of adding values to a collection and testing whether a value already exists in that collection. 
One more point of advice: when you're reading a file, you typically want to use the `with open(...)` pattern -- this ensures the file is closed when you're done with it, even if an error occurs.

Comment: @danjl You mentioned "I have attempted the use of sets and dictionary.fromkeys with no success" - that's the attempt I'm talking about, i.e. what did you try, and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sets to eliminate duplicates:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

pattern = re.compile("[^/]*\.js")

matches = set()
with open('access_log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for match in re.findall(pattern, line):
            #x = str(match) # or just use match
            if match not in in matches:
                print match
                matches.add(match)
```

**But I question your regex:**

You are doing a `findall` on each line, which suggests that each line might have multiple "hits", such as:

```
file1.js file2.js file3.js
```

But in your regex:

```
[^/]*\.js
```

`[^/]*` is doing a greedy match and would return only one match, namely the complete line.

If you made the match non-greedy, i.e. `[^/]*?`, then you would get 3 matches:

```
'file1.js'
' file2.js'
' file3.js'
```

But that highlights another potential problem. Do you really want those spaces in the second and third matches for these particular cases? Perhaps in the case of `/abc/ def.js` you would keep the leading blank that follows `/abc/`.

So I would suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

pattern = re.compile("""
    (?x)            # verbose mode
    (?:             # first alternative:
        (?<=/)      # positive lookbehind assertion: preceded by '/'
        [^/]*?      # matches non-greedily 0 or more non-'/'
    |               # second alternative
        (?<!/)      # negative lookbehind assertion: not preceded by '/'
        [^/\s]*?    # matches non-greedily 0 or more non-'/' or non-whitespace
    )
    \.js            # matches '.js'
    """)

matches = set()
with open('access_log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for match in pattern.findall(line):
            if match not in matches:
                print match
                matches.add(match)
```

If the filename cannot have any whitespace, then just use:

```
pattern = re.compile("[^\s/]*?\.js")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `set` wouldn't work, what was wrong there? Did you try it as below?

```
import re
import sys

pattern = re.compile("[^/]*\.js")
results = set()

for i, line in enumerate(open('access_log.txt')):
    for match in re.findall(pattern, line):
        results.add(str(match))
```